# Bootstrap 3 form-control not stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone check this code please, i really dont know what i'm doing wrong,

I'm using T3 Blank and Twitter Bootstrap 3 to create this form

the fields are not stacking with the form-grouo div width for some reason, heres the print:

[image]

Any help would be apreciated

and heres the code for the form

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well sombra-externa">
            <div class="fonte-main"><h4>Complete seu cadastro!</h4></div>
            <legend></legend>
            <form id="completar-cadastro" class="form-horizontal clearfix">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="fisica"><input name="tipopessoa" value="fisica" id="fisica" type="radio"> Pessoa Física</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="juridica"><input name="tipopessoa" value="juridica" id="juridica" type="radio"> Pessoa Jurídica</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="nomecliente">Nome *</label><input name="nomecliente" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Seu nome completo" id="nomecliente" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="cpf">CPF *</label><input name="cpf" value="" placeholder="Insira seu CPF" id="cpf" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <label for="cpf">DDD *</label><input name="ddd" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="DDD" id="ddd" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <label for="cpf">Telefone *</label><input class="form-control" name="telefone" value="" placeholder="Insira seu CPF" id="telefone" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="cpf">CEP *</label><input name="cep" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira seu CEP" id="cep" type="text">
                </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well sombra-externa">colocar passos</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle helps in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to have clean spacing between the fields, I would just remove the `form-control` class from each of the divs as they are not necessary, and then add some margin to the stacked divs:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well sombra-externa">
            <div class="fonte-main"><h4>Complete seu cadastro!</h4></div>
            <legend></legend>
            <form id="completar-cadastro" class="form-horizontal clearfix">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="fisica"><input name="tipopessoa" value="fisica" id="fisica" type="radio"> Pessoa Física</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="juridica"><input name="tipopessoa" value="juridica" id="juridica" type="radio"> Pessoa Jurídica</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="nomecliente">Nome *</label><input name="nomecliente" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Seu nome completo" id="nomecliente" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="cpf">CPF *</label><input name="cpf" value="" placeholder="Insira seu CPF" id="cpf" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <label for="cpf">DDD *</label><input name="ddd" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="DDD" id="ddd" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <label for="cpf">Telefone *</label><input class="form-control" name="telefone" value="" placeholder="Insira seu CPF" id="telefone" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="cpf">CEP *</label><input name="cep" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira seu CEP" id="cep" type="text">
                </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well sombra-externa">colocar passos</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and some CSS to add spacing between each stacked layer:

```
fieldset div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/EWTM508m5d).

On your site, you have the following defined in *both* `template.css` and `bootstrap.css`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .inputbox {
   width: auto; 
}
```

You should remove this as it is causing the problems you have above.

Comment: Thats it but my form dont stack with the proper width for some reason, as you can see the class form-control for the fields are not being aplyed correctly, heres the link http://marqueicerto.com.br/planos/checkout.html

Comment: Edited - the problem is the custom CSS that you have.

Comment: You should also simplify `class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"` to just `class="col-xs-6"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this ***TheBootstrapWayTM*** here's the solution:

You're wrapping each individual form group in a `col-*-6` class. What you're telling Bootstrap is not only "stack these items" but also "treat these items as columns in a row and display them inline." You should pick one or the other.

Look what I've done in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmblackwood/52VtD/7392/

Here you can see I've wrapped the first four items you want to stack in one column *in* their own column:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-control">...</div>
  <div class="form-control">...</div>
```

... and so on.

If you put two columns next to each other, they'll both display stacked, and each within their own column. Oh and also, you don't need to put `.col-lg-* col-super-large-* ..etc.` if you are using the same column width across all screen sizes. Because Bootstrap is mobile-first, `col-xs-6` will suffice.